# Boost Threads equivalent to Python's threading.Event?

Tags: python, multithreading, events, boost

Is there a [Boost Threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/thread/) equivalent to Python's [`threading.Event`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects)

Less specifically, is there a synchronization primitive that allows threads to pass when an internal value is set, and blocks them when not?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Boost's [condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref). Condition variables avoid some of the pitfalls that can happen with event objects. I find it hard to use event objects correctly in some corner cases: multiple triggers before the event is handled, some state is changed before the handler is called, etc.

The examples in the Boost documentation are quite self-explanatory.

Comment: I'm not sure anything in Boost is self-explanatory.